# Ionic application not connecting to internet after signing

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Ionic application not able to connect to internet after signing the application.

`<access origin="*"/>`   is there in `config.xml`

Unsigned apk is working in mobile.

Also tried changing `http <-> https` nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">-->
```

try it ?

Comment: in index.html ?

Comment: index.html , yes .